# Redis sorted set and pagination challenge at edge cases

Tags: node.js, redis, leaderboard, sortedset

We have implemented a **leaderboard** with a **Redis sorted set**. This works awesome when the score is not updating frequently but in case of our leaderboard score updates so frequently due to that we got an issue of redundant entry in pagination!

Example code!

Adding and incrementing Redis sorted set with a score.

```
lbRedisClient.ZINCRBY(lbKey, score, userid);
```

Get leaderboard with pagination

```
lbRedisClient.ZREVRANGE(lbKey, from, to, 'WITHSCORES');
```

Now let's see the **edge case**

Every page contains 10 records, on the first page, I got 10 players and one of *playerOne* at rank 10 with a score 55. Let's assume that before calling next page *playerOne* dropped to rank 11 with score 54, so on the next page again I got that player and it shows redundant entry.

Similarly what about a new player who is at rank 10 who was new to top ten players?

Do anyone know how to resolve this issue! What should I do in this kind of scenario?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the desired behavior? This sounds "correct" as is to me, in the sense that the reordered leaderboard is already reflected accurately to the user.